How could they know if someone apparated in or out of Harry's house?
In Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Moody mentions that Thicknesse has made Apparation in the Dursley's house an imprisonable offense.

“All right, all right, we’ll have time for a cozy catch-up later,” roared Moody over the hubbub, and silence fell in the kitchen. Moody dropped his sacks at his feet and turned to Harry, “As Dedalus probably told you, we had to abandon Plan A. Pius Thicknesse has gone over, which gives us a big problem. He’s made it an imprisonable offense to connect this house to the Floo Network, place a Portkey here, or Apparate in or out. All done in the name of your protection to prevent You-Know-Who getting in at you. Absolutely pointless, seeing as your mother’s charm does that already. What he’s really done is to stop you from getting out of here safely."
Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows - Chapter 3

To enforce this though, the ministry would need a way to know if the people were apparating in or out. How would they go about doing this?

I don't know if this has been asked before, but I did do some research in SF & F but found nothing.

Related, but probably not a duplicate strictly-speaking: If The Ministry has the power to detect what specific spells have been used, how didn't they know that Morfin's memory had been edited?

Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/240984/if-apparation-cannot-be-tracked-then-why-did-it-matter-that-the-department-of-m

In theory, there are a range of known charms that can detect the presence of another person.

The Caterwauling Charm will trigger an effect when someone unexpected apparates into a place.







The Intruder Charm will warn a wizard that someone has apparated nearby.


‘And yet you must have moved fairly quickly to prepare such a welcome
for us at such short notice,’ said Dumbledore. ‘You can’t have had
more than three minutes’ warning?’
Slughorn said, half-irritably, half-proudly, ‘Two. Didn’t hear my
Intruder Charm go off, I was taking a bath. Still,’ he added sternly,
seeming to pull himself back together again, ‘the fact remains that
I’m an old man, Albus. A tired old man who’s earned the right to a
quiet life and a few creature comforts.’
Harry Potter and Half-Blood Prince

That all being said, you've hit the nail on the head with your quote. The goal isn't to prevent people apparating in, it's to make it illegal for Harry to apparate (or have any other ready method of escape) in the event of an attack by Voldemort's henchmen as soon as he turns 17 and loses the protection of the house.
